# Moving clocks observed with different observers

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation

If a clock is moving near to speed of light with constant velocity it'll slow down, but if I were to observe from the clock will the observer on Earth slow down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of the clock's frame of reference, the clock itself is at rest and the Earth is moving.  So yes, clocks on Earth will be observed to be running more slowly.  The clock itself will be observed to be running at its "normal" rate.

Comment: But then how twin paradox exists? Should they be aged same?

Comment: No, because in the twin paradox each twin experiences a different history.  One is always in an inertial frame, the other is not.